# How to read this calligraphy? What does it mean?

Tags: calligraphy, writing-identification

What are all the characters in this calligraphy? Overall, what does it mean?

[image: front view]

as per the accepted answer, just wanted to share the complete porcelain set I have. It is kind of cool:

[image]

Comment: You got only that as a gift?  That is strange.   See: http://page.auctions.yahoo.co.jp/jp/auction/207069912

Comment: @l'électeur yes! I have the figurines as well! Now, I know who gave me that wooden sign! And, only a 1000 yen going away present... ouch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says 「[陶]{とう}びな　[元光作]{げんこうさく}」.

That means "Ceramic Hina Dolls Produced by Genkou"

The ひ-to-び change is by [rendaku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku).

In case anyone is unfamiliar with Hina-Matsuri, [Wiki has it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinamatsuri).